# Why TARGET_OS_WATCH is equal to 0 in "WatchKit Extention" target?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, c-preprocessor

I have iOS project with **"WatchKit Extention"**. Also I mustn't import **SSKeychain.h** there. So I decided to use proprocessor macross:

```
#if TARGET_OS_WATCH == 0
#import "SSKeychain.h"
#endif
```

But I've got preprocessor isue(screenshot bellow). Why TARGET_OS_WATCH is equal to 0 for **"WatchKit Extention"** target?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My app had been created before the first apple watch release. At that time **"iOS SDK"** was used as **"Base SDK"**. I haven't recrete this target. So today my **Watch Kit App** know nothing about **Watch OS SDK**. And **TARGET_OS_WATCH** is equal to 0 there.

The same for **"Watch Kit Extention"**
[image]